# item appears more than n/2 times in the array A

Tags: algorithm

An array `A[1 : : : n]` is populated by items form some infinite set S. (S need not be a set of
numbers, and an order relation need not be dened on it.) Describe an algorithm with a
worst-case time complexity which is O(n) to determine whether some item appears more than
n/2 times in the array A. Do not forget to argue that your algorithm is correct and that T(n)
is indeed O(n).

Comment: The answer is not that difficult, show atleast some attempt at solving it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a two step process.

1. Get an element occurring most of the time in the array. This phase will make sure that if there is a majority element then it will return that only.
2. Check if the element obtained from above step is majority element.

Pseudocode:

```
findCandidate(a[], size)
1.  Initialize index and count of majority element
     maj_index = 0, count = 1
2.  Loop for i = 1 to size – 1
    (a) If a[maj_index] == a[i]
          count++
    (b) Else
        count--;
    (c) If count == 0
          maj_index = i;
          count = 1
3.  Return a[maj_index]
```

Check if the element obtained in step 1 is majority

```
printMajority (a[], size)
1.  Find the candidate for majority
2.  If candidate is majority. i.e., appears more than n/2 times.
       Print the candidate
3.  Else
       Print "NONE"
```

[reference](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/majority-element/)

Comment: How is the recurrence relation for this algorithm?

Comment: @ShaimaaEbid, It is not recursive algorithm, so no recurrence relation. It is basically 2 loops, hence O(n).

Comment: I want to write divide and conquer algorithm